# Is it possible to have the Notepad++ title bar just say "Notepad++"?

Tags: notepad++

Is it possible to have the Notepad++ title bar just say "Notepad++"?

The the reason is, I want my button on the taskbar to just say "Notepad++". I have many tabs in Notepad open and go there for many reasons, so I just need it to say Notepad++ on my taskbar.

It seems like there are currently only two options:
1. the full path.
2. the "file name " + "Notepad++"

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is not possible. You could either [make a feature request](https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/issues) or [download the source code](https://github.com/donho/notepad-plus-plus) and fix it yourself.

Comment: @DavidPostill – Hi David, could you please convert your answer from comment to answer so it can receive regular upvotes, downvotes and can be accepted?

Comment: @miroxlav Done. Answer added. The OP hasn't returned since he asked the question though.

Comment: What does it say on your taskbar?

Answer (score 4):

#### Is it possible to have the Notepad++ title bar just say "Notepad++"?

It is not possible. You could either [make a feature request](https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/issues) or [download the source code](https://github.com/donho/notepad-plus-plus) and fix it yourself.

Comment: This is the beauty of open source. Don't like it? Fix it.  Might even go so far as to fix it and hide it behind a preference option and submit a patch set to the maintainer(s)